# Volley Request Finish error

Tags: android, android-volley

i am working in application in which i use volley for making call to web-services the scenario is like that when i pressed back button i m calling finish() and then when i try to open app from recent apps section request is made for login (the app get minimized before request is made) and Log cat is saying Request.finish below is line for retry policy   `stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(40000 *2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));` if still other code is required i will post ...any help is appriciated

Here is the Code for Volleyrequest.java
public class VolleyRequest {

```
private static VolleyRequest instance;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private Gson gson;
private Map<String, Integer> urlWiseResponseCheck = null;
// host address url


public static final String HOST_URL = "Host Url";

private static final String HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE = HOST_URL + "private/mobile/v1/";
private static final String HOST_ADDRESS_PUBLIC = HOST_URL + "public/mobile/v1/";

/**
 * 1 == loginAuthentication
 */
public static final String CHECK_LOGIN_AUTH = HOST_ADDRESS_PUBLIC + "check-login-authentication/";
/**
 * 2 == add user
 */
public static final String ADD_USER = HOST_ADDRESS_PUBLIC + "add-user/";
/**
 * 3 == add user with picture
 */
public static final String ADD_USER_WITH_PIC = HOST_ADDRESS_PUBLIC + "add-user-with-pic/";
/**
 * 4 == get workout calorie map
 */

public static final String GET_WORKOUT_CALORIE = HOST_ADDRESS_PUBLIC + "get-workout-calorie-map/";
/**
 * 5 == add activity record
 */
public static final String ADD_ACTIVITY_RECORD = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "add-activity-record/";

/**
 * 6 == add history pictures
 */
public static final String ADD_HISTORY_PICTURE = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "add-history-picture/";

/**
 * 7 == update logout flag
 */
public static final String SET_LOGOUT_FLAG = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "set-logout-flag/";

/**
 * 8 == get history by history id
 */
public static final String GET_HISTORY = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "get-history/";

/**
 * 9 == get history by user id
 */
public static final String GET_HISTORY_BY_ID = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "get-user-history/";
// friend request
/**
 * 10 == add friend request
 */
public static final String ADD_FRIEND_REQUEST = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "add-friend-request-record/";

/**
 * 11 == change friend status
 */
public static final String CHANGE_STATUS = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "change-friend-req-status/";

/**
 * 12 == change trace status
 */
public static final String CHANGE_TRACE_STATUS = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "change-trace-status/";

/**
 * 13 == get friend with trace status
 */
public static final String GET_FRIEND_WITH_TRACE_STATUS = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "get-friend-with-trace-status";

/**
 * 14 == get user with friend status
 */
public static final String GET_ALL_USER_WITH_STATUS = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "get-all-friend-with-status/";
/**
 * 15 == get tracer user list
 */
public static final String GET_TRACED_USER_LIST = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "get-all-trace-user/";
/**
 * 16 == send invitation mail
 */
public static final String SEND_MAIL = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "send-mail/";
/**
 * 17 == add user log
 */
public static final String ADD_USER_LOG = HOST_ADDRESS_PUBLIC + "add-log-file";
/**
 * 18 == delete history
 */
public static final String DELETE_USER_HISTORY = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "delete-user-history/";

public static final String AUTH_TOKEN_REQUEST = HOST_URL + "oauth/token";

public static final String SET_SHARE_FLAG = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "share-user-history/";

/**
 * 20 == Get last activity
 */
public static final String GET_LAST_ACTIVITY = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "get-last-activity/";

public static final String GET_CHALLENGE = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "get-challenges/";

public static final String SUSPEND_CHALLENGE = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "suspend-challenge/";

public static final String INVITE_PARTICIPANTS = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "invite-participants/";

public static final String SAVE_CHALLENGE = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "save-challenge/";

public static final String JOIN_CHALLENGE = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "join-challenge/";

public static final String GET_CHALLENGE_PARTICIPANT = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "get-challenge-participant/";

public static final String GET_PARTICIPANTS = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "get-participants/";

public static final String REMOVE_PARTICIPANT = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "remove-participant/";

public static final String JOIN_OPEN_CHALLENGE = HOST_ADDRESS_PRIVATE + "join-open-challenge/";

/**
 * define final constant
 */
private final int CHECK_LOGIN_AUTH_VALUE = 1;
private final int ADD_USER_VALUE = 2;
private final int ADD_USER_WITH_PIC_VALUE = 3;
private final int GET_WORKOUT_CALORIE_VALUE = 4;
private final int ADD_ACTIVITY_RECORD_VALUE = 5;
private final int ADD_HISTORY_PICTURE_VALUE = 6;
private final int SET_LOGOUT_FLAG_VALUE = 7;
private final int GET_HISTORY_VALUE = 8;
private final int GET_HISTORY_BY_ID_VALUE = 9;
private final int ADD_FRIEND_REQUEST_VALUE = 10;
private final int CHANGE_STATUS_VALUE = 11;
private final int CHANGE_TRACE_STATUS_VALUE = 12;
private final int GET_FRIEND_WITH_TRACE_STATUS_VALUE = 13;
private final int GET_ALL_USER_WITH_STATUS_VALUE = 14;
private final int GET_TRACED_USER_LIST_VALUE = 15;
private final int SEND_MAIL_VALUE = 16;
private final int ADD_USER_LOG_VALUE = 17;
private final int DELETE_USER_HISTORY_VALUE = 18;
private final int SET_SHARE_FLAG_VALUE = 19;
private final int GET_LAST_ACTIVITY_VALUE = 20;
public static final int GET_CHALLENGE_VALUE = 21;

private final int SUSPEND_CHALLENGE_VALUE = 22;
private final int INVITE_PARTICIPANTS_VALUE = 23;
public static final int JOIN_CHALLENGE_VALUE = 24;
public static final int GET_CHALLENGE_PARTICIPANT_VALUE = 25;
public static final int GET_PARTICIPANTS_VALUE = 26;
public static final int REMOVE_PARTICIPANT_VALUE = 27;
public static final int JOIN_OPEN_CHALLENGE_VALUE = 28;


private VolleyRequest() {
}

public static VolleyRequest getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new VolleyRequest();
    }
    return instance;
}

/**
 * initialization Url with Map
 */

public void initializationUrlMap() {
    gson = CommonUtil.getGson();
    if (urlWiseResponseCheck == null) {
        urlWiseResponseCheck = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(CHECK_LOGIN_AUTH, CHECK_LOGIN_AUTH_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(ADD_USER, ADD_USER_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(ADD_USER_WITH_PIC, ADD_USER_WITH_PIC_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(GET_WORKOUT_CALORIE, GET_WORKOUT_CALORIE_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(ADD_ACTIVITY_RECORD, ADD_ACTIVITY_RECORD_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(ADD_HISTORY_PICTURE, ADD_HISTORY_PICTURE_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(SET_LOGOUT_FLAG, SET_LOGOUT_FLAG_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(GET_HISTORY, GET_HISTORY_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(GET_HISTORY_BY_ID, GET_HISTORY_BY_ID_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(ADD_FRIEND_REQUEST, ADD_FRIEND_REQUEST_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(CHANGE_STATUS, CHANGE_STATUS_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(CHANGE_TRACE_STATUS, CHANGE_TRACE_STATUS_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(GET_FRIEND_WITH_TRACE_STATUS, GET_FRIEND_WITH_TRACE_STATUS_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(GET_ALL_USER_WITH_STATUS, GET_ALL_USER_WITH_STATUS_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(GET_TRACED_USER_LIST, GET_TRACED_USER_LIST_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(SEND_MAIL, SEND_MAIL_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(ADD_USER_LOG, ADD_USER_LOG_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(DELETE_USER_HISTORY, DELETE_USER_HISTORY_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(SET_SHARE_FLAG, SET_SHARE_FLAG_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(GET_LAST_ACTIVITY, GET_LAST_ACTIVITY_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(GET_CHALLENGE, GET_CHALLENGE_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(SUSPEND_CHALLENGE, SUSPEND_CHALLENGE_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(INVITE_PARTICIPANTS, INVITE_PARTICIPANTS_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(JOIN_CHALLENGE, JOIN_CHALLENGE_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(GET_CHALLENGE_PARTICIPANT, GET_CHALLENGE_PARTICIPANT_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(GET_PARTICIPANTS, GET_PARTICIPANTS_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(REMOVE_PARTICIPANT, REMOVE_PARTICIPANT_VALUE);
        urlWiseResponseCheck.put(JOIN_OPEN_CHALLENGE, JOIN_OPEN_CHALLENGE_VALUE);
    }
}

/**
 * send server request using volley
 *
 * @param url
 * @param parameterJson
 * @param object        object[0] == context variable object[1] == Object variable
 */
public void sendRequest(final String url, final String parameterJson, final Object... object) {
    if (!CommonUtil.TRY_OUT_USER || url.equals(VolleyRequest.GET_WORKOUT_CALORIE)) {
        if (CommonUtil.isNetworkAvailable((Context) object[0])) {
            if (!url.equals(VolleyRequest.GET_TRACED_USER_LIST) && !url.equals(VolleyRequest.GET_WORKOUT_CALORIE) && !url.equals(VolleyRequest.GET_LAST_ACTIVITY) && !url.equals(VolleyRequest.GET_FRIEND_WITH_TRACE_STATUS)) {
                if (progressDialog != null) {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog((Context) object[0], R.style.CustomProgressDialog);
                startProgressDialog();
            }
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    getResponse(response, url, parameterJson, object);
                }

            }, new ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    onError(error, url, parameterJson, object);
                }

            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    return getParameter(url, parameterJson, object);
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    if (url.equals(CHECK_LOGIN_AUTH) || url.equals(ADD_USER) || url.equals(ADD_USER_WITH_PIC) || url.equals(ADD_USER_LOG)) {
                        return CommonUtil.getHeaders((Context) object[0], false);
                    } else {// private request
                        return CommonUtil.getHeaders((Context) object[0], true);
                    }
                }
            };
            stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000 *2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

            VolleySingleton.getInstance((Context) object[0]).addRequest(stringRequest);
        } else {
            AlertMsg.showToast((Context) object[0], "You do not have internet connection");
        }
    }
}

private void onError(VolleyError error, String url, String parameterJson, Object[] objects) {
    if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
        CommonUtil.EXPIRE_TIME = null;
        sendRequest(url, parameterJson, objects);
    } else {
        dismissProgressDialog();
        AlertMsg.networkAlertDialog((Context) objects[0]);
    }
}

/**
 * get response from server
 *
 * @param response
 * @param url
 * @param parameterJson
 * @param object
 */
private void getResponse(String response, String url, String parameterJson, Object... object) {
    dismissProgressDialog();
    if (response != null) {
        int value = urlWiseResponseCheck.get(url);
        switch (value) {
            case CHECK_LOGIN_AUTH_VALUE:
                UserInfo userInfo = gson.fromJson(parameterJson, UserInfo.class);
                if ((Context) object[0] instanceof SplashScreenActivity) {
                    CommonUtil.checkAuthentication((Context) object[0], response, true, userInfo.getPassword());
                } else if ((Context) object[0] instanceof LoginActivity) {
                    CommonUtil.checkAuthentication((Context) object[0], response, false, userInfo.getPassword());
                } else if ((Context) object[0] instanceof GetPushNotificarionFromParse) {
                    ((GetPushNotificarionFromParse) object[0]).getResponse(response);
                } else if ((Context) object[0] instanceof TraceUserActivity) {
                    ((TraceUserActivity) object[0]).getLoginResponse(response);
                }
                break;
            case ADD_USER_VALUE:
                UserInfo userInfo2 = gson.fromJson(parameterJson, UserInfo.class);
                if (object.length > 1 && object[1] instanceof AccountDetailFragment) {
                    ((AccountDetailFragment) object[1]).getResponse(userInfo2);
                } else if (object.length > 1 && object[1] instanceof SettingMenuActivity) {
                    ((SettingMenuActivity) object[1]).getResponse();
                } else {
                    if (userInfo2.isFirstTime()) {
                        CommonUtil.setSubscriptionFlag((Context) object[0], true);
                    }
                    CommonUtil.showMainActivity((Context) object[0], response, userInfo2.getPassword());
                }

                break;
            case GET_WORKOUT_CALORIE_VALUE:
                Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<Double, Double>>>() {
                }.getType();
                Map<String, Map<Double, Double>> workoutCalorieMap = gson.fromJson(response, type);
                CommonUtil.setWorkoutCalorieMap(workoutCalorieMap);
                break;
            case ADD_ACTIVITY_RECORD_VALUE:
                if (object[0] instanceof AddWorkoutDetails) {
                    ((AddWorkoutDetails) object[0]).finish();
                } else if (object[1] instanceof SaveActivityRecord) {
                    ((SaveActivityRecord) object[1]).getResponse(response);
                } else if (object[1] instanceof MainFragment) {
                    CommonUtil.getUserHistory().setId(response);
                }
                break;
            case SET_LOGOUT_FLAG_VALUE:
                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences((Context) object[0]);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString(ActivityConstant.EMAIL, null);
                editor.putString(ActivityConstant.USER_PASSWORD, null);
                editor.commit();
                Intent intent = new Intent((Context) object[0], LoginActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                ((Activity) object[0]).startActivity(intent);
                ((Activity) object[0]).finish();
                break;
            case GET_HISTORY_VALUE:
                if (object[1] instanceof HistoryFragment) {
                    ((HistoryFragment) object[1]).getResponse(response);
                } else if (object[1] instanceof TotalWorkoutDetailFragment) {
                    ((TotalWorkoutDetailFragment) object[1]).getResponse(response);
                }

                break;
            case GET_HISTORY_BY_ID_VALUE:
                if ((Context) object[0] instanceof TraceUserActivity) {
                    ((TraceUserActivity) (Context) object[0]).getResponse(response);
                } else if (object.length > 1 && object[1] instanceof HistoryFragment) {
                    ((HistoryFragment) object[1]).getHistoryItem(response);
                }
                break;
            case CHANGE_STATUS_VALUE:
                if ((Context) object[0] instanceof GetPushNotificarionFromParse) {
                    ((GetPushNotificarionFromParse) object[0]).getResponse();
                } else if ((Context) object[0] instanceof PendingUserList) {
                    ((PendingUserList) object[0]).finish();
                }
                break;
            case CHANGE_TRACE_STATUS_VALUE:
                if ((Context) object[0] instanceof GetPushNotificarionFromParse) {
                    ((GetPushNotificarionFromParse) object[0]).getResponse();
                }
                break;
            case GET_FRIEND_WITH_TRACE_STATUS_VALUE:
                if (object[1] instanceof FriendFragment) {
                    ((FriendFragment) object[1]).getResponse(response);
                } else if (object[1] instanceof ShowTraceFriendActivity) {
                    ((ShowTraceFriendActivity) object[1]).getResponse(response);
                }
                break;
            case GET_ALL_USER_WITH_STATUS_VALUE:
                Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<UserWithFriendStatus>>() {
                }.getType();
                List<UserWithFriendStatus> allRecordList = gson.fromJson(response, collectionType);

                if (object[0] instanceof AddFriendFromContact) {
                    ((AddFriendFromContact) object[0]).getRecordFromServer(allRecordList);
                } else if (object[0] instanceof AddFriendFromHealthWel) {
                    ((AddFriendFromHealthWel) object[0]).getRecordFromServer(allRecordList);
                } else if (object[0] instanceof PendingUserList) {
                    ((PendingUserList) object[0]).getRecordFromServer(allRecordList);
                } else if (object[0] instanceof ParticipantHw) {
                    ((ParticipantHw) object[0]).getRecordFromServer(allRecordList);

                }
                break;
            case GET_TRACED_USER_LIST_VALUE:
                if (object[1] instanceof MainFragment) {
                    ((MainFragment) object[1]).getTraceUserResponse(response);
                }
                break;
            case ADD_USER_LOG_VALUE:
                if (object[1] instanceof SplashScreenActivity) {
                    ((SplashScreenActivity) object[1]).getResponse();
                }
                // ((MainActivity) (Context) object[0]).finish();
                break;
            case DELETE_USER_HISTORY_VALUE:
                if ((Context) object[0] instanceof OverViewActivity) {
                    ((OverViewActivity) object[0]).getResponse();
                }
                break;
            case SET_SHARE_FLAG_VALUE:
                if ((Context) object[0] instanceof FacebookIntegration) {
                    ((FacebookIntegration) object[0]).getResponse();
                } else if ((Context) object[0] instanceof GooglePlusIntegration) {
                    ((GooglePlusIntegration) object[0]).getResponse();
                }
                break;
            case GET_LAST_ACTIVITY_VALUE:
                if ((Context) object[0] instanceof MainActivity) {
                    ((MainActivity) object[0]).getLastActivityResponse(response);
                }
                break;
            case GET_CHALLENGE_VALUE:
            case SUSPEND_CHALLENGE_VALUE:
            case INVITE_PARTICIPANTS_VALUE:
            case JOIN_CHALLENGE_VALUE:
            case GET_CHALLENGE_PARTICIPANT_VALUE:
            case GET_PARTICIPANTS_VALUE:
            case REMOVE_PARTICIPANT_VALUE:
            case JOIN_OPEN_CHALLENGE_VALUE:
                if (object[1] instanceof ResponseListener) {
                    ((ResponseListener) object[1]).onResponse(response, value);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * getParameter VolleyRequest
 *
 * @param url
 * @param parameters
 * @param object
 * @return Map<String,String>
 */
private Map<String, String> getParameter(String url, String parameters, Object[] object) {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    int value = urlWiseResponseCheck.get(url);
    if (value == CHECK_LOGIN_AUTH_VALUE || value == ADD_USER_VALUE) {
        params.put(ActivityConstant.USER_JSON, parameters);
    } else if (value == SET_LOGOUT_FLAG_VALUE || value == GET_HISTORY_VALUE || value == GET_FRIEND_WITH_TRACE_STATUS_VALUE || value == GET_ALL_USER_WITH_STATUS_VALUE
            || value == GET_TRACED_USER_LIST_VALUE || value == GET_LAST_ACTIVITY_VALUE || value == GET_CHALLENGE_VALUE) {
        params.put(ActivityConstant.USER_ID, CommonUtil.getUserInfo().getId());
    } else if (value == CHANGE_STATUS_VALUE || value == CHANGE_TRACE_STATUS_VALUE) {
        params.put(ActivityConstant.FRIEND_JSON, parameters);
    } else if (value == GET_HISTORY_BY_ID_VALUE || value == DELETE_USER_HISTORY_VALUE) {
        params.put(ActivityConstant.HISTORY_ID, parameters);
    } else if (value == SET_SHARE_FLAG_VALUE) {
        params.put(ActivityConstant.HISTORY_ID, parameters);
        if ((Context) object[0] instanceof FacebookIntegration) {
            params.put(ActivityConstant.FACEBOOK_SHARE, ActivityConstant.FACEBOOK_SHARE);
        } else {
            params.put(ActivityConstant.FACEBOOK_SHARE, ActivityConstant.GOOGLE_SHARE);
        }
    } else if (value == ADD_FRIEND_REQUEST_VALUE) {
        params.put(ActivityConstant.ADD_FRIEND, parameters);
    } else if (value == ADD_USER_LOG_VALUE) {
        params.put(ActivityConstant.ADD_LOG_FILE, parameters);
    } else if (value == SEND_MAIL_VALUE) {
        if ((object[0] instanceof AddFriendFromHealthWel) || object[0] instanceof ParticipantHw) {
            UserInfo receiverUser = (UserInfo) object[1];
            String subject = ActivityConstant.FRIEND_REQUEST_SUBJECT.replace("{SENDER_NAME}", CommonUtil.getUserInfo().getFirstName());
            String body = ActivityConstant.FRIEND_REQUEST_BODY.replace("{RECEIVER_NAME}", receiverUser.getFirstName()).replace("{SENDER_NAME}", CommonUtil.getUserInfo().getFirstName());
            params.put(ActivityConstant.MAIL_TO, parameters);
            params.put(ActivityConstant.MAIL_SUBJECT, subject);
            params.put(ActivityConstant.MAIL_BODY, body);
        } else if (object[0] instanceof AddFriendFromContact) {
            if (object[1] != null) {
                UserInfo receiverUser = (UserInfo) object[1];
                String subject = ActivityConstant.FRIEND_INVITATION_SUBJECT.replace("{SENDER_NAME}", CommonUtil.getUserInfo().getFirstName());
                String body = ActivityConstant.FRIEND_REQUEST_BODY.replace("{RECEIVER_NAME}", receiverUser.getFirstName()).replace("{SENDER_NAME}", CommonUtil.getUserInfo().getFirstName());
                params.put(ActivityConstant.MAIL_TO, parameters);
                params.put(ActivityConstant.MAIL_SUBJECT, subject);
                params.put(ActivityConstant.MAIL_BODY, body);
            } else {
                UserInfo receiverUser = (UserInfo) object[1];
                String subject = ActivityConstant.FRIEND_REQUEST_SUBJECT.replace("{SENDER_NAME}", CommonUtil.getUserInfo().getFirstName());
                String body = ActivityConstant.FRIEND_REQUEST_BODY.replace("{RECEIVER_NAME}", receiverUser.getFirstName()).replace("{SENDER_NAME}", CommonUtil.getUserInfo().getFirstName());
                params.put(ActivityConstant.MAIL_TO, parameters);
                params.put(ActivityConstant.MAIL_SUBJECT, subject);
                params.put(ActivityConstant.MAIL_BODY, body);
                // TODO : friend request.
            }
        } else if (object[0] instanceof MainActivity) {
            params.put(ActivityConstant.MAIL_TO, parameters);
            String subject = ActivityConstant.ERROR_LOG_TEMPLATE.replace("{USER_ID}", CommonUtil.getUserInfo().getId());
            params.put(ActivityConstant.MAIL_SUBJECT, subject);
            params.put(ActivityConstant.MAIL_BODY, ActivityConstant.log);
        }
        dismissProgressDialog();
    } else if (value == ADD_ACTIVITY_RECORD_VALUE) {
        params.put(ActivityConstant.ACTIVITY_RECORD_JSON, parameters);
    } else if (value == SUSPEND_CHALLENGE_VALUE || value == GET_PARTICIPANTS_VALUE) {
        params.put(ActivityConstant.CHALLENGE_ID_JSON, parameters);
    } else if (value == INVITE_PARTICIPANTS_VALUE) {
        params.put(ActivityConstant.INVITE_PARTICIPANT_JSON, parameters);
    } else if (value == JOIN_CHALLENGE_VALUE) {
        params.put(ActivityConstant.CODE_JSON, (String) object[2]);
        params.put(ActivityConstant.USER_ID, CommonUtil.getUserInfo().getId());
        if (CommonUtil.isNotNull(parameters)) {
            params.put(ActivityConstant.PAYMENT_JSON, parameters);
        }
    } else if (value == GET_CHALLENGE_PARTICIPANT_VALUE) {
        params.put(ActivityConstant.CODE_JSON, parameters);
    } else if (value == REMOVE_PARTICIPANT_VALUE) {
        params.put(ActivityConstant.CHALLENGE_ID_JSON, parameters);
        params.put(ActivityConstant.PARTICIPANT_ID, (String) object[2]);
    } else if (value == JOIN_OPEN_CHALLENGE_VALUE) {
        params.put(ActivityConstant.CHALLENGE_ID_JSON, parameters);
        params.put(ActivityConstant.USER_ID, (String) object[2]);
    }
    return params;
}

/**
 * start Progress Dialog
 */
public void startProgressDialog() {
    if (progressDialog != null && !progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

}

/**
 * dismiss Progress Dialog
 */
public void dismissProgressDialog() {
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post your code

Comment: for VolleyRequest @peeyush?

Comment: for request plus the code where you are creating a volley request

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: expected behaviour is if login is succesfull then redirect to main screen @David

Comment: What's happening in                   `CommonUtil.checkAuthentication((Context) object[0], response, true, userInfo.getPassword());`?

Comment: just for Login service response

Comment: Aha... And where is the "logic" for the redirect as you said: "expected behaviour is if login is succesfull then redirect to main screen"

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        mContext.startActivity(intent); see this line in Showmainactivity method

Comment: i figure out the problem it is actually depand on one static variable ..thank u so much to all for your quick response..